# ALTER TABLE - ADD Column in vb.net will always add the a table?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm querying through vb.net using SQL Server. I want to alter my table in database by adding another column example (age) in the form load is this going to add another table every time I execute/start my code? Thank you :)

Comment: Isnt this something you could test in less time that it took to post this?

Comment: form load runs every time the form loads...so isn't that a pretty clear indication of how often your code will try to create a table?

Comment: i dont want to try it yet because it is a company record so i want to be sure.

Comment: or maybe i need create another table with age only and use join statement?

Comment: what you write there makes no sense. You cannot alter a table by adding another table. What is it that you want to do ? Your question is not clear and makes no sense

Comment: sorry i want to add another column in my existing table by querying it through vb.net

Comment: If you are wanting to add a new column in a table every time a form loads your design is not good. I could see adding a new row as an audit but adding a new column just screams that something is very very wrong here.

Comment: The answer to your current question is NO it will not add another table everytime your form is loaded. It will however try to create the same column over and over again

Comment: no i dont need answers actually i need opinion on how im going to add another column on my table. even me i dont think adding column in the table in form loader is not going to be good.

Comment: Not good is a gross understatement. It is a horrible idea. You should go back to the person who is asking you to do this and explain why it is so bad. What happens when the form is loaded 10,000 times???

Comment: how about join statement? is this going to help me?

Answer (score 1):

Would it be an idea to first check if the column exists and then create it if it needs creating? (If you try to create a column that already exists you will get an exception.)

E.g.:

```
IF NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE
            TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
            AND TABLE_NAME = 'yourTableName'
            AND COLUMN_NAME = 'age'
    )

ALTER TABLE ...
```

Comment: thats not the point its sure that the table has no age in it, so i want to add one by putting the query in vb.net

Comment: Surely if this SQL code executes each time you run your VB.net code you would be trying to create the same table each time? Your question seems to suggest that was your concern?

Comment: yes i need a suggestion i dont want to ruin the record. i dont know what im going to need. i think i need to create another table and use join statement?

Comment: Are you creating a table or adding a column to an existing table?

Comment: adding a column to an existing table but my only choice is query it through vb.net

Comment: so you are not trying to create another table, please edit your question then

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect how I'd go about this for a new column.